# How to fit data to a piecewise function?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, statistics, least-squares, piecewise-continuity

My question today regards a set of data that I wish to fit a piecewise-defined continuous function. This data set covers a domain of x-values from $0$ to $\mu$ on the x-axis.

What I need is to determine a value $x_0 \in {\rm I\!R}+$ and two functions of given forms $f_1: [0, x_0] \mapsto {\rm I\!R}$ and $f_2: [x_0, \mu] \mapsto {\rm I\!R}$ such that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are both continuous and $f_1(x_0) = f_2(x_0)$ and $f_1 \cup f_2$ is the piecewise function of this type which best fits the data.

Can I please have some information/instruction on the background theory regarding how to do this? Would linear least squares and elementary multivariable calculus be enough given that $f_1$ and $f_2$ must both be smooth on $(0, x_0)$ and $(x_0, \mu)$ respectively?

In this case, I need to find $f_1 = ax^\frac{3}{2}$ for some $a \in {\rm I\!R}$ and $f_2 = bx + c$ for some $b, c \in {\rm I\!R}$ such that $b \in [-d,d]$ for some given $d \in {\rm I\!R}$; so the goal is essentially to find a piecewise function consisting of a power law curve and a line that is nearly horizontal which best fits the data I am looking at.

I would very much appreciate help on this problem if you would be so kind.

Comment: Google "piecewise regression" or "segmented regression".  Also, you'll need to be able to state if $d$ is known or needs to be estimated along with the other parameters.  And finally, is the variability about the two segments the same?  You might want to consult with a statistician.

Comment: @JimB thank you so much, sir, for your reply. In this case, we may just make a hack and set $d$ to some arbitrary value, but we would like to know if there is a general solution. I have no idea whether the variability is the same; I can only assume so, since the data for both parts of the curve is taken from the same instrument during the same measurement.

Comment: Usually it requires an iterative estimation process.  Rarely is there a closed-form solution.  But if you're willing to "just make a hack", I hope it's not for anything important.

Comment: @JimB you might have a good point about that - simply making a hack could be a bad idea. The next time I meet with my PI, I will discuss with him the best way to determine $d$.

Comment: Good.  The usual approach is to let the data estimate all of the parameters including $d$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression.

Comment: As long as the two models are linear with respect to parameters, it is pretty simple and very unexpensive fixing $d=x_k$ (the $x$being sorted first) and varying $k$. When the best $k$ has been obtained, you have very good estimates adn you can easily polish all parameters (including $d$) using a simple optimizer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the first portion of the piecewise function is (should be according to theory) a power-law and is nonlinear. The second portion of the function is linear

Comment: As @ClaudeLeibovici stated your model IS linear with respect to the parameters.  Not knowing that is another reason to consult a statistician.

Comment: JimB gave the answer. By the way, I have been using this method for decades on the basis of very highly nonlinear models (nonlinear with respect to parameters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what software package you might want to use but here is one of many ways to estimate the parameters using *R*.

First note that for the resulting function to be continuous you need

$$a x_0^{3/2} = b x_0 + c$$

So we could take $c = a x_0^{3/2} - b x_0$.

```
# Generate data from a segmented model and plot it
  a = 2
  b = 0.125
  x = c(0:50)/10
  x0 = 2
  c = a*x0^(3/2) - b*x0
  set.seed(12345)
  y = (x<x0)*a*x^(3/2) + (x>=x0)*(b*x+c) + rnorm(51,0,0.5)
  plot(x,y, las=1)

# Function to calculate sum of squared distance from observed value
  ss = function(parameters, y) {
    a = parameters[1]
    b = parameters[2]
    x0 = parameters[3]
    c = a*x0^(3/2) - b*x0
    sum((y - ((x<x0)*a*x^(3/2) + (x>=x0)*(b*x + a*x0^(3/2) - b*x0)))^2)
  }
```

Now with some starting values (and good starting values are very valuable) find the estimates that minimize the sum of squares:

```
sol = optim(c(1.5,0.1,1.5), ss, y=y)
sol$par
#[1] 2.05963514 0.04598089 2.01290367
```

Plot the data and the fit:

[image: Data and fit]

Comment: Wonderful answer, thank you. My research group uses Matlab and I am not aware that any of us are familiar with $R$. However, I am certain that we will take your advice here into account. I will keep the question open for now in case there is any more input that could be helpful, whether from you or from other users.

Comment: upon further evaluation of your answer, I think you may have mistaken $d$ for the value I referred to as $x_0$ in the problem statement. If this is a mistake, can you please amend your answer? $x_0$ is supposed to be the knot/transition value for the piecewise function, not $d$. $d$ is just a positive number that specifies the range of acceptable slope values for the line segment

Comment: What I didn't include was the estimation of confidence intervals for the parameters or for the predictions.  When you do use Matlab, I would argue it is essential to report on the "goodness" of the fitted function.

Comment: Got it.  I'll change $d$ to $x_0$.